# Non-expiring session in box view

Tags: box-view-api

How can I create a non-expiring session in Box view?
I know that you can change the session time with

```
curl https://view-api.box.com/1/sessions \
-H "Authorization: Token YOUR_API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"document_id": "THE_DOCUMENT_ID", "duration": 60}' \
-X POST \
-i
```

but What should I put in the duration value?

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to create a non-expiring session. You can set the session to expire at a time really far ahead in the future, though that's a bit of a hack.